# Jquery FadeIn Messes Up Float Div

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a bar at the top of my page.  When a user scrolls past `700 px` jquery will put the formerly hidden logo into the bar using this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(posFromTop > 700){
    $('#logo').fadeIn(200, function(){
    });

    } else {
    $('#logo').fadeOut(200, function(){
    });
    }
});
```

That works great, but I have a link in that bar that gets pushed down when the `#logo` appears.  How can i prevent the link from moving when the `#logo` appears.

Link code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style='height: 50px; background-color:rgba(242, 244, 247, 0.5); width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 30;'>
<a href='#' id='logo' style='font-size: 40px;'>logo</a>
<a href='#t' style='position: absolute; right: 12px;'>Start</a>
```

Logo code:

```
#logo{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: absolute` on the logo to prevent it from affecting other content.

Comment: sure except i can't figure out how to scroll in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PwX93/

Comment: It doesn't move in at least Chrome, Firefox, or IE11. Here's an updated fiddle with `<br>` tags to allow scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/PwX93/1/.

Comment: yeah you're right.  i updated my code.  maybe it has something to do with the fact that the bar has a `fixed` position

Answer (score 0):

Before doing all the script work, first keep both element visible and align the way it has to be and then execute script.

Comment: could you elaborate.  why would i want to keep the logo visible?

Comment: Issue is not because of scroll event, but it is html/css issue. If you keep both #logo and link visible you will get the same issue what happend when you call scroll event. So you can fix the issue first then turn #logo to hidden state and then execute your script.

Comment: im sorry i still don't understand.  could you provide some code?